# Function calls with class members?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, callback, non-static

Before I present the code which is found at the bottom of this post I would like to talk about the issue and the fix's that I do not desire. Okay basically I've created a GUI from scratch sort of and one requirement I wanted for this was allow components to have their own click executions so if i click a button or tab etc.. It would call Component->Execute(); Well normally you would do something like a switch statement of ids and if that components ID equaled n number then it would perform this action. Well that seemed kinda dumb to me and I thought there has to be a better way. I eventually tried to incorporate a feature in JAVA where you would do like Component.AddActionListener(new ActionListener( public void execute(ActionEvent ae) { })); or something like that and I thought that this feature has to be possible in C++. I eventually came across storing void functions into a variable in which could be executed at any time and modified at any time. However I hadn't noticed an issue and that was this only worked with static functions. So below you'll see my problem. I've patched the problem by using a pointer to SomeClass however this would mean having an individual function call for every class type is there no way to store a function callback to a non-static class member without doing the below strategy? and instead doing a strategy like the commented out code?

//Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream> //system requires this.
#include "SomeClass.h"

void DoSomething1(void)
{
    std::cout << "We Called Static DoSomething1\n";
}

void DoSomething2(void)
{
    std::cout << "We Called Static DoSomething2\n";
}

int main()
{
    void (*function_call2)(SomeClass*);
    void (*function_call)() = DoSomething1; //This works No Problems!
    function_call(); //Will Call the DoSomething1(void);
    function_call = DoSomething2; //This works No Problems!
    function_call(); //Will Call the DoSomething2(void);

    SomeClass *some = new SomeClass(); //Create a SomeClass pointer;
    function_call = SomeClass::DoSomething3; //Static SomeClass::DoSomething3();
    function_call(); //Will Call the SomeClass::DoSomething3(void);
    //function_call = some->DoSomething4; //Non-Static SomeClass::DoSomething4 gives an error.
    //function_call(); //Not used because of error above.
    function_call2 = SomeClass::DoSomething5; //Store the SomeClass::DoSomething(SomeClass* some);
    function_call2(some); //Call out SomeClass::DoSomething5 which calls on SomeClass::DoSomething4's non static member.
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

//SomeClass.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class SomeClass 
{
    public:
        SomeClass();
        ~SomeClass();

    public:
        static void DoSomething3(void);
        void DoSomething4(void);
        static void DoSomething5(SomeClass* some);
};
```

//SomeClass.cpp

```
#include "SomeClass.h"

SomeClass::SomeClass(void)
{

}

SomeClass::~SomeClass(void)
{

}

void SomeClass::DoSomething3(void)
{
    std::cout << "We Called Static DoSomething3\n";
}

void SomeClass::DoSomething4(void)
{
    std::cout << "We Called Non-Static DoSomething4\n";
}

void SomeClass::DoSomething5(SomeClass *some)
{
    some->DoSomething4();
}
```

Secondary Fix for what I'll do not an exact answer I wanted but it meets my needs for now along with allowing additional features which would have become overly complicate had this not existed.

//Component.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <d3d9.h>

#include "Constants.hpp"
#include "ScreenState.hpp"
#include "ComponentType.hpp"

using namespace std;

class Component 
{

    static void EMPTY(void) { }
    static void EMPTY(int i) { }

    public:
    Component(void)
    {
        callback = EMPTY;
        callback2 = EMPTY;
        callback_id = -1;
    }

    Component* SetFunction(void (*callback)())
    {
        this->callback = callback;
        return this;
    }

    Component* SetFunction(void (*callback2)(int), int id)
    {
        this->callback_id = id;
        this->callback2 = callback2;
        return this;
    }

    void execute(void)
    {
        callback();
        callback2(callback_id);
    }

}
```

Comment: You will get more help if you add the C++ tag

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for pointers-to-member-functions is as follows:

```
struct Foo
{
    void bar(int, int);
    void zip(int, int);
};

Foo x;

void (Foo::*p)(int, int) = &Foo::bar;   // pointer

(x.*p)(1, 2);                           // invocation

p = &Foo::zip;

(x.*p)(3, 4);                           // invocation
```

Mind the additional parentheses in the function invocation, which is needed to get the correct operator precedence. The member-dereference operator is `.*` (and there's also `->*` from an instance pointer).

Comment: I assume that's the proper way to do what I was saying with the SomeClass.DoSomething4?


the issue I have let me try to clarify a little better though is the following: I'd like it to were i can store any kind of function to a single variable this way i can call something like "Execute(void);" and it'll execute that function pointer. It would be very similar how in java the action events for buttons, labels, etc.. work. Is it possible to convert the above into a template class so I'm not forced to use Foo and instead can use anything? Kinda like Object in Java

Comment: Edit: this does look a bit useful and i'm going to attempt to modify it a bit for my usage maybe i'll be able to come up with something before new comments appear.

Comment: @user1625157: The type of the class is part of the function pointer type. You can't have a generic `"Anything"::*(int,int)` type...

Comment: Hmm damn would by any chance know how like lets say the win32 handles button clicks? so each button can perform it's own action? Sorry to make you answer so many questions this is just an issue which is driving me crazy and I can't seem to find a source file of the windows.h class to try figuring this out either.

Comment: The Windows API only deals with free functions. Those are totally different from *member* functions. Think about it: A member function makes no sense without an object instance. Where should that fit in in your picture?

Comment: Hmm well thanks for the amount of help you were able to do i'll keep trying to find a comfortable solution. I really don't want to resort to something like "Component->GetID() == #" or a switch of that aswell.

Comment: I just want you to appreciate the deep conceptual difference between a free function and a member function before you get fixated on some idea. The usual solution for dealing with C APIs is to exploit some extra-data field like a `void*` in the callback to pass an instance pointer and then make a static function to perform the actual call via that instance pointer. It hinges on whether the C API provides such a "context" field.

Comment: Well what i ended up doing which will work out nicely enough for the needs of this program is the following I added a second functioncall but this one accepts an int value and you must store an id so i do the following "Component->SetFunctionCall(SOME_FUNCTION, id);" so now when you do "Execute(void);" it'll do "function(id);" i have both function calls set to "Empty(void) { }" and "Empty(int a) { }" this way if nothing is stored it just does nothing when executed and the id is set to -1 not that it matters. So what i do is "SomeFunc(id) {options[id]->SetEnabled();}" which was what i neeeded.

Comment: Sorry that i'm not exactly understanding what your talking about I've only been doing C++ for a little bit now. I've mostly dealt with JAVA and these issues never occurred to me or the problem were easily solvable. If you'd like additional information on what this project i'm working on involved It's a simple gui system built for some software i'm making and I needed components to have their own individual "click" events or operations this seems to be the most logical solution but doesn't seem to work as nicely as it could in JAVA. I wanted to learn more on DirectX & C++ for game development.